# vlookup-like javascript to map input value from one field to another

Tags: javascript, html, forms, quickbase

I am just starting html/javascript, and attempting to create a simple form that populates a specific "Customer Code" when a "Customer Name" is selected from an input list (behaving like an excel vlookup). The examples I found on stackoverflow all resulted in alert windows, but I would like the value to populate in the form.

Here's my html snippet for the Customer Name dropdown list:

```
<select id="customername">
<option></option>
<option>Doe Inc</option>
<option> Smith LLC </option>
<option> Rogers and Co </option>
```

Here's the customername to customercode mapping:
Doe Inc = 276. Smith LLC = 852. Rogers and Co = 552.

I would like the customercode to update to the respective customername whenever the customername is updated (without the need for a button), as this is part of a larger form that will an Submit button (in other words, I don't want users to have to click "Submit" to retrieve the customercode, then "Submit" again later in the form).

Thanks!

Comment: Is customercode supposed to be a visible input, or is it a hidden field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to be included in a form submission, your form controls need to successful controls, which at the simplest means they need a `name=""` value:

```
<select id="customername" name="customername">
    <option></option>
    <option>Doe Inc</option>
    <option> Smith LLC </option>
    <option> Rogers and Co </option>
</select>
```

If what you actually care about submitting is the customercode, and the customername is just the "friendly" version, add the `value` attribute to your options, and rename the select appropriately:

```
<select id="customercode" name="customercode">
    <option value="">Select one...</option>
    <option value="276">Doe Inc</option>
    <option value="852">Smith LLC </option>
    <option value="552">Rogers and Co </option>
</select>
```

If you want both "values" to be visible on the form and included in the form submission, you could use a `data-` attribute to sync a readonly input:

```
<select id="customername" name="customername">
    <option data-value="">Select one...</option>
    <option data-value="276">Doe Inc</option>
    <option data-value="852">Smith LLC </option>
    <option data-value="552">Rogers and Co </option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="customercode" id="customercode" readonly />
```

Then use some JavaScript to sync them:

```
var select = document.getElementById('customername');
select.onchange = function(e) {
  var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].dataset.value;

  var input = document.getElementById('customercode');
  input.value = value;
}
```

Example jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/27jx0q3a/3/

Some links, to help:

- [W3C: Successful controls](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)
- [MDN: Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you were looking for.
Basically, I used an array to format your numbers, then used the onchange onto the select element and waited for a change. When a change occurs, I fire an event and Javascript gets the values of the field, compares them with the array and returns based on the selected value.

### Please refer to Tieson T. Reply, has way more explanations and different approaches for static html!

```js
var drop_down = document.getElementById("customername");
var result = document.getElementById("result");
var list_array = {
  "": "Please Select A Value",
  "Doe Inc": 276,
  "Smith LLC": 852,
  "Rogers and Co": 552
}

function change_value() {
  if (list_array[drop_down.value]) {
    result.innerHTML = list_array[drop_down.value];
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="customername" onchange="change_value()">
  <option></option>
  <option>Doe Inc</option>
  <option>Smith LLC</option>
  <option>Rogers and Co</option>
</select>
  
<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: Probably should update `change_value` to clear `result` if `list_array[drop_down.value]` is falsey, to handle the "blank" option. +1 anyway.

Comment: Good sir! I literally just updated it haha! Thanks for the correction, also great explanation on your post.

Comment: I don't think that note you just added is really necessary. Your version is perfectly valid.

Comment: Comparing the amount of details you wrote, for a beginner, your reply is worth 10x more the effort than reading mine. I even learned something from your post as a novice programmer. Thank you!

Comment: thanks so much! i'm going to use the method described by Tieson T in this thread, but will use this method for a different question I had